# Exterior of a Jordan Curve conformally mapped onto the exterior of the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $\gamma$ is a Jordan Curve. $\Omega_0$,$\Omega_1$ are the "inside" and "outside" of $\gamma$ respectively. By Riemann Mapping theorem, there exists a $f$ that conformally maps $\Omega_0$ onto $\{|z|<1\}$. (By conformal map $f$ I mean a bijection $f$ such that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are both analytic).

Does there also exist a $g$ that conformally maps $\Omega_1$ onto $\{|z|>1\}$?

I know the answer is affirmative. But I am looking for a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a\in\Omega_0$. Then $z\mapsto 1/(z-a)$ maps $\Omega_1$ to the interior
of a Jordan curve $\gamma'$ but with one point (zero) removed. We can map
the interior of $\gamma'$ to the open unit disc, then the image of $\Omega_0$
gets mapped to the disc minus one point. A linear fractional transformation
will then send that point to the origin. Now apply $z\mapsto 1/z$.